# I can't stop executing a function

Tags: javascript

My problem is that I can't stop executing a function and it is causing me a big problem. This function is a function that I perform when the modal is opened and it is waiting for me to submit the form to register or update the data. The problem is that every time I close and open this modal, it executes the function depending on how many times I opened this modal. For example: if I open the modal for the first time, register and close. If I open it again, it will register the value I enter and it will register again but an empty data. My code is a bit long because I split it up to be able to optimize it. I'm using the "realtime database", from firebase

This is the code for the floating buttons. I click on a button and it shows another two buttons, one for registering categories and another for products. Clicking on any of them opens a specific modal

```
function modalFloatButtons_options() {
    let floatButtonAdd = document.getElementById("carte_modalFloatAddBtn");
    let modalFloatButtonsOptions = document.querySelector(".modalFloatButtons_options");
    
    modalFloatButtonsOptions.style.display = "none";


    // Functions
    // Open or close div
    function openCloseOptions() {
        floatButtonAdd.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            if(modalFloatButtonsOptions.style.display == "none"){
                modalFloatButtonsOptions.style.display = "block";
                optionsAnimation_openClose("block");
                modalFloatButton_options_btnsEnvetListener()
            }else{
                optionsAnimation_openClose("none");

                setTimeout(() => {
                    modalFloatButtonsOptions.style.display = "none";
                }, 251);                
            }
        })
    }openCloseOptions()

    // Options animation
    function optionsAnimation_openClose(display) {
        if(display == "block"){
            modalFloatButtonsOptions.animate([
                { bottom: '10%' },
                { bottom: '120%' }
            ], {
                duration: 250,
            })
        }else{
            modalFloatButtonsOptions.animate([
                { bottom: '120%' },
                { bottom: '0%' }
            ], {
                duration: 250,
            })
        }
    }

    // Float buttons - options - event listener
    function modalFloatButton_options_btnsEnvetListener() {
        let modalFloatButtonOptionsBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".modalFloatButtons_options_btn");
        
        modalFloatButtonOptionsBtn.forEach(element => {
            element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
                modal_openModal(e.target.id.substr(4), "create")
            })
        });
    }
}modalFloatButtons_options()

// Open modal
function modal_openModal(id, method, data, key) {
    let div = document.getElementById(id);
    div.style.display = "flex";

    modal_closeModal(div, id);
    if(id == "modalCategory"){
        modalAddCategory("execute", method, data, key)
    }else if(id == "modalProduct"){

    }
}

// Close modal
function modal_closeModal(div, id) {
    let closeBtn = document.querySelector("#"+id+" .modal_closeBtn");

    div.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        if(e.target.id === div.id || e.target.classList[1] === "modal_closeBtn"){
            div.style.display = "none";
            modalAddCategory("break")
        }
    })
}
```

When he clicks the button, he will see the id and execute the function

```
function modalAddCategory(execute, method, updateData, key){
    let form = document.querySelector("#modalCategory form");
    let submitbtn = document.querySelector("#modalCategory form button");
    let categoryInput = document.querySelector("#modalCategory form input[name='categoryTitle']");
    
    // Putting value in the input if it is for update
    if(method == "update"){
        categoryInput.value = updateData.category
    }
    console.log(method)
    console.log("--------")

    // Event listener - submit btnm
    realtimedb_eventSubmitBtn(submitbtn, categoryData, form);


    // Data
    function categoryData() {
        let data = {
            category: categoryInput.value
        };

        // Register data
        if(method == "update"){
            realtimedb_update("Categories", data, key)
        }else if(method == "create") {
            realtimedb_create("Categories", data);
        }
    }
}
```

And it is and the function that is giving me trouble

```
// Event listener - submit btn 
function realtimedb_eventSubmitBtn(btn, nameFunction, form) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", (element) => {
        element.preventDefault();

        nameFunction();
    
        form.reset();
    })
}
```

I tried to use return but it didn't work, someone please help me

Comment: Yes, simply because you add another click listener every time you open the modal. You define a listener inside a function inside another function, not sure why you're nesting things like that, but every time one of these functions is executed, another click listener is being added. So you click once, you get multiple functions executions.

Comment: Yes, I know that is the problem. But how can I stop executing when closing the modal?

Comment: If you want to "stop executing" a function, you just have to use `return`. But I don't understand why you want to stop a function execution. Your problem is that you add multiple click listeners, the solution is to add only one, not to stop a function's execution. Reorganize your code and add only one click listener. And not inside a function that's inside a function (why do this??), but simply add it once.

Comment: I did so because I don't want code to be executed unnecessarily. It should only be executed when it is meant to do so.